FAIL - Application at context path /OpenClinica could not be started
Can you please help.
I am extremely new to databases. I am trying to download OpenClinica database on my laptop.
I compeleted all the setup step.
database type = postgres
I also downloaded tomcate and it is working on my laptop. Whenever I try to start /openclinica it fails
screenshot from Tomcat
Catalina.log shows the following:
Apr 10, 2024 9:21:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.util.ProductInfo.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1776)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.buildParamsString(UpdateChecker.java:125)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.buildUpdateCheckUrl(UpdateChecker.java:121)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.doCheck(UpdateChecker.java:69)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(UpdateChecker.java:60)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.run(UpdateChecker.java:51)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Any clue how to resolve this?
I made sure of the Java, tomcat and postgresql compatibility

Your WAR file has not deployed. Try to look in the log files (catalanexxx.log) for the cause; may be some data source has not been configured correctly. In most cases the error should also print in the console when you start Tomcat with ./catalina.sh run
